# Convert string into array

Tags: php, array

i am getting following string from POST. i want to convert this string in to array. please help me how i can do this?

```
[{Product Id=3423654000000343061, Discount=0.00, Line Tax=Sales Tax===0:::0;;;, Product Name=.5mL (Sunset Sherbet), Quantity=100.0, Tax=0.00, Total After Discount=1450.0, Net Total=1450.00, Quantity in Stock=597.0, Total=1450.00, List Price=14.50, Unit Price=16.0, Product Description=.5mL / 0.016 fl. oz.}]
```

Comment: An array of what?  String, or Product2 object, or something else?  Please edit your original post to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

What format do you need? By the case you wanna split by `,` you can do something like this:

```
String str = '[{ ...... }]';
str = str.right(str.length()-2);
str = str.left(str.length()-2);
String[] listStr = str.split(',');
```

Anyway it could be worthier using a wrapper or JSON.